# How can we pour water in a container without making noise?

Tags: acoustics

We usually hear sound of splash when we pour water in a container.How can we pour water in a container without making noise?

I think that the answer may be to pour it infinitesimally slowly.Am I correct?

Comment: Hold the bottom of the container below the dew point. Pass humid air above the dew point over/into the container. Wait.

Comment: Re, "infinitesimally slowly" If you try to pour water very slowly, then surface tension will break the stream of water into a sequence of drops.

Answer (score 2):

Do it in the vacuum. Since sound is the mechanical wave, you just need to prevent it from propagate mechanical vibration to your ear.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound

Comment: But if there's water present, then it isn't really vacuum. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There will always be some sound produced when you pour the water. You can just slowly pour the water along the sides of the container and the sound produced will be almost inaudible.